Is any Hamiltonian time reversal symmetric?
Of course it shouldn't be.  Please shoot me down.
Let $H$ be a single-particle Hamiltonian.  It is time reversal symmetric if there exists some $U_T$ satisfying:
$$
\begin{split}
U_T^{\dagger}\,  U_T &= 1, \, U_T^{*} \, U_T = \pm 1; \\
U_T^{\dagger} \, H^{*} \, U_T &= H.
\end{split}
$$
My understanding based on Schnyder et. al. is that I don't have to discuss specifically how spin, momentum or whatnot transform under time reversal.  I can keep the state labels all abstract, and just focus on the above condition.
Being a Hamiltonian, $H$ should be Hermitian.  It is therefore diagonalizable by some unitary $J$, and it has only real eigenvalues.  Let $\tilde{H}$ be the diagonal form:
$$
J \, H \, J^{\dagger} = \tilde{H} = \tilde{H}^{*} = J^{*} \, H^{*} \, J^{t}.
$$
Now if I just identify $U_T = J^{t} J$.  This guy is obviously unitary, turns $H^{*}$ into $H$, and satisfies $U_T^{*} \, U_T = 1$.  Thus one can define a time-reversal symmetry for any Hamiltonian as long as it is Hermitian.
I am very confused at this point.  It will be greatly appreciated if anyone can tell me what goes wrong here.
--edit--
@hft suggests in the comment that my question is similar to this one.
Well, in that question, the answer reached was "if a Hamiltonian is unitarily equivalent to its complex conjugate, it is time reversal symmetric."  Here I just showed that any Hamiltonian is unitarily equivalent to its complex conjugate.
Not only is that previous question not helpful, I have serious issue with that answer.
--edit 2--
My confusion is largely cleared thanks to @Andrew and @mikestone.  Let me summarize my new-found understanding here.
As far as the mathematical classification goes, one must first define "time reversal" with respect to a particular basis and stick with it throughout.  $U_T$ comes pre-determined, and all we can do is to test whether a Hamiltonian is invariant under this particular $U_T$.  Physically speaking, we know what time reversal is before we have the Hamiltonian.
(Otherwise, as demonstrated above, I can always cook up a $U_T$ with all the correct properties for any Hamiltonian.  The whole thing just becomes meaningless.)
Consider the physical example of a 4-site spinless fermion hopping problem with magnetic flux.  The Hilbert space is spanned by $| n \rangle$, with periodic identification $| n + 4 \rangle = | n \rangle$.  Given the physical meaning, we would want to take simply $U_T = 1$.
The Hamiltonian is
$$
H = \sum_{n=1}^{4} t | n \rangle \langle n+1 | + h.c.
$$
In the presence of a magnetic flux, $t$ is complex.  Then this Hamiltonian is not invariant with $U_T = 1$.
While I can cook up some $\tilde{U_T}$ that seemingly keeps $H$ invariant, that "time reversal" operation mixes lattice sites.  Is it a "hidden symmetry" of this particular $H$?  Yes.  Can we find an entire class of Hamiltonians that share the same symmetry?  You bet.  But is it a physically useful thing to do?  Not quite.  For one thing, it is easily broken by a site-dependent chemical potential, a rather mundane perturbation.
More importantly, if I decide that time reversal is instead given by that $\tilde{U_T}$, I have to stick with it.  With this definition, the $t \in \mathbb{R}$ model becomes T-non-invariant instead.  As @mikestone remarked, mathematically you will come up with a similar classification scheme anyway, but you may not want it that way for physical reasons.

What does your $U_T$ have to do with time?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer $U_T$ has nothing to do with time.  The action on wavefunction is $T: \psi{t} \rightarrow U_T \psi(-t)$, and $U_T$ is responsible for the non-time part.

The time reversal operator should be antilinear. Isn't $J^t J$ going to be linear by construction?

@Vokaylop the reason I'm asking is, it seems to me that I could have replaced every instance of the word "time" in your post by "chakra" and nothing about the argument would have changed, if indeed $U_T$ has nothing to do with time. Can I?

@Andrew $H$ gets complex conjugated.  That's the antilinear bit.  $U_T$ is the remaining unitary transformation.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer See $H^*$ up there?  That complex conjugation flips the sign of time evolution in Schroedinger equation.  $U_T$ is just not responsible for that part.

You should be able to frame your "proof" as the construction of a time reversal operator that is anti-unitary and anti-linear. When I point out that the operator $J^t J$ is not anti-linear, you wave your hands and point to some other thing you've written down. Where is your specific operator that is anti-unitary and anti-linear? If you don't have a single operator you can point that is meant to implement time reversal to then I don't understand your question.

@Andrew Let $K$ be the antilinear complex conjugation operator with $K^{\dagger} K = 1$.  $T H T^{\dagger} = U_T K H K^{\dagger} U_T^{\dagger} = U_T  H^{} K K^{\dagger} U_T^{\dagger} = U_T  H^{} U_T^{\dagger}$.  The $U_T$ operator is just plain old unitary, and the fact that $H$ get conjugated means there is an implicit antiunitary bit in the transformation.

So you are saying your time reversal operator is $T=U_T K$ where $K$ represents complex conjugation?

Similar to: Why does time reversal symmetry requires a real Hamiltonian?.

@Andrew Yes.  Or I might as well simply define $T H T^{\dagger} = U_T H^{} U_{T}^{\dagger}$ without invoking a separate $K$.  Then we come back to my earlier statement that $H \rightarrow H^{}$ is the antilinear bit of the whole affair.

Hey, I'm the one helping you :) An example of an interaction that breaks time reversal invariance is an electric dipole interacting with an external electric field, $\mu \cdot E$. By the Wigner Eckhart theorem, $\mu \propto S$. Note $S$ changes sign under time reversal and $E$ does not. If we take $E=E_z$, and a spin-1/2 particle, the interaction is proportional to $\sigma_z$. The $J$ which diagonalizes this is just $1$, so your $T$ would be "complex conjugation followed by multiplication by $1$", but this would not flip $S = \hbar/2 \sigma_z \rightarrow -\hbar/2 \sigma_z = -S$, which is wrong

@Andrew I think what you're saying is that you insist on $U_T \sim \sigma_y$ regardless of what the Hamiltonian actually is.  So basically you have a notion of what time reversal entails before you even take a single look at the Hamiltonian, and if it doesn't fit then $H$ is not T-invariant.  I can stomach that much, but is that view consistent with how the random matrix people came up with their 10-fold way?

Yeah I think I agree with that. One thing I would want the time reversal operator to do is be a representation of time reversal in the Poincaire group, which would flip the sense of angular momentum. I think your construction works in the sense that it will produce a Hamiltonian that reverses dynamics of the Schrodinger equation, but it may not do everything physically implied by the words "time reversal". I have no idea what the 10 fold way is and have no comment on that :)

@Andrew is there some simple explanation for how electric interaction $\mu\cdot E$ can break time reversal invariance in QT, and what exactly that means? Can you link to some analysis of this statement? It seems words are used differently that in classical EM theory/mechanics, where both electric and magnetic terms in the Hamiltonian are the same functions of coordinates and momenta, and have the same value in both directions of time (e.g. $q\phi$,$\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf A$, $-\mathbf m \cdot \mathbf B$ are the same formulae and same values in both directions of time).

@Andrew when a movie of a $\psi$-description of an atom with non-zero magnetic moment and electric moment is played in reverse, the playback should show an atom with opposite magnetic moment and opposite external magnetic field but same electric moment and same external electric field, right?

The algebra here is, as far as I can see correct, but there is a conceptual issue that has confused me in the past. In @Vokaylop's  construction we find a $U_T$ that is constructed  for this particular hamiltonian. In  other words $U_T$ depends on $H$. The Dyson-Altland-Zirnbauer classification  is set up to descibe classes of Hamilonians, and so given a $U_T$ we want to find all matrices that satisfy $U_TH^*U_T^{-1} =H$ for that  fixed $U_T$. For example the  Gaussian Orthogonal ensemble class  is that which given a fixed basis of the Hilbert space consists of   all matrices that have real  entries in that fixed basis.  This class is the above  construction for the choice $U_T={\mathbb I}$.
The choice  $U_T={\mathbb I}$ may seem special, but we can write the condition $U_TH^*U_T^{-1} =H$ as $U_TH^tU_T^{-1} =H$ and under change of basis for $H$ we find that $U\to V^tUV$ and a complex symmetric matrix that squares to ubity can always be diagonalized to ${\mathbb I}$ in this way, so $U_T= {\mathbb I}$ is not a special case.
In other words the set of matrices that are real (and so symmetric) in the basis that gives @Vokaylop's  diagonal $\tilde H$ are counted as "time reversal" invariant for his  $J^tJ$, but this may not be a physical   time reversal operation.

Following from a discussion in the comments, I was wondering if it's also the case that you could fine a $U_T$ that did reverse the Schrodinger time evolution, but didn't have other properties you would want for time reversal? For example, time reversal should switch the sign of spin components. So an interaction like $H_{int} = \mu S \cdot E$ should violate time reversal. But if $E=E_z$ and $S=\hbar/2 \sigma_z$, then $U_T=1$ will mathematically work to conjugate the Hamiltonian but won't flip $S_z$ (or else it would flip $S_z$ and also flip $E$ even though it shouldn't, physically).

@Andrew Yes. I think that we  should first choose $U_T$ to flip spins etc, and then look at the class of $H$ that are conjugated into $H^*$ by that choice. As far as the topological homotopies are concerned all choices of $U_T$ that obey $U_T= U_T^t$ give the same homotopy classification, and that  is what Schnyder and co are after.

Thank you.  That clears up my confusion a lot.  Please also see my edit for a follow-up discussion.

There’s no problem with your time-reversal symmetry definition or your observation about the Hermiticity of $H$ and its diagonalizability.
Which brings us to your choice of $U_T = J^t J$:
a)  it does satisfy $U_T^† H^* U_T = H$, but not necessarily all the conditions for a time-reversal operator.
b)  to be specific - the condition $U_T^* U_T = \pm 1$ isn’t guaranteed by this construction.
Time-reversal symmetry imposes additional constraints on the structure of the Hamiltonian beyond just Hermiticity.
Not all Hermitian Hamiltonians are time-reversal symmetric. A system with a magnetic field breaks time-reversal symmetry for example.
The existence of a time-reversal symmetry often implies degeneracies in the energy spectrum (Kramers degeneracy for half-integer spin systems), which not all Hamiltonians possess.
So, while all time-reversal symmetric Hamiltonians are Hermitian, not all Hermitian Hamiltonians are time-reversal symmetric.

Write your TeX inside of dollar signs or double dollar signs for it to render correctly on the screen.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Thanks for the prompt on TeX.

No problem. Looks better. :)

$U_T^{} , U_T = J^{\dagger} , J^{} , J^{t} , J = J ^{\dagger} , (J ,J^{\dagger}) ^{t} J = 1$ given that $J$ is unitary.  It is guaranteed by the construction.

The antilinearity of the time reversal operator is required in  the many body second-quantized Hilbert space. It is not required in the $H= U^\dagger H^* U$ context. I am confused by this also,

Your condition $U_T^\dagger H^* U_T = H$ is inconsistent with the notion that $U_T$ is a symmetry at all. A symmetry of $H$ means the operator representing that symmetry must commute with $H$. Therefore:
$$
U_T^\dagger H U_T=U_T^\dagger U_T H = H \neq H^*
$$
Perhaps you could clarify where exactly in the paper you retrieved that expression from, maybe you misread it or accidentally modified it.

Page 5, equation 1b of Schnyder.  No, $U_T$ itself is not necessarily a symmetry of $H$.

I see, this is supposed to be only the unitary part of the time-reversal operator. In which case, yes, you can always find a "custom-made" operator for that particular $H$ that maps you from $H^*$ to $H$ s.t. tacking on a complex conjugation operator on it $(U = U_T K)$ is an anti-unitary symmetry operator of $H$ and looks kind of like time reversal. In that case, you should read Mike Stone's answer if you haven't already.
